# How to replace strings avoiding making second order replacements?

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I have a text file and I want to make a text replacement. However, my problem this time is that the new text also includes text that originally exists in the original file and that appears in the hash of replacements.

How can I replace text but only once per line, avoiding making "second order" replacements?

Normally I do replacements with sed where I use col1 and col2 file for the replacement. col1 has the original string to replace; col2 the new one.

#### input file:

```
ID1 X1 X2 X3
ID2 X3 X4 X5
```

```
col1    col2 of "hash" used for replacement:
X1      X2 X3
X2      X7
X3      X8
```

#### output after replacement with sed

```
ID1 X7 X3 X7 X8
ID2 X3 X4 X5
```

#### Expected output

```
ID1 X2 X3 X7 X8
ID2 X8 X4 X5
```

#### bash command used

```
paste col1 col2 | while read n k; do sed -i \"\" \"s/$n/$k/g\" input; done
```

Comment: Thanks for edit by wrong format. The expected values for ID1 are these ones because originally ID1 had X1, X2 and X3, which are mapped by X2 X3, X7, and X8 respectively on the hash.

Comment: I'm not clear what you want your input for the replacement to look like. Your `paste` command implies that you have two files `col1` and `col2`; is that what you want?

Comment: @Borodin Yes I have 2 files; col1 has the "keys" to replace on the input file and col2 has the "values" or the new text to add. Originally both are in one file and I split that to run the bash command on this way.

Comment: I see you're getting answers using regexps. Hopefully it's glaringly obvious that if you're trying to map **a literal string** to **another literal string** then doing so by employing regexps and then quoting and/or escaping characters and/or adding boundaries and/or doing anything similar with the regexp or replacement to try to make them behave like literal strings is the wrong approach compared to simply using literal strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some Perl code that reads the replacement hash from `repl.txt`. It looks like

#### repl.txt

```
X1      X2 X3
X2      X7
X3      X8
```

The input is read from the `DATA` file handle. You can easily modify this by opening a file of your own. The simplest way is to specify the path to the input file as a parameter on the command line; then you can just change `<DATA>` to `<>`: no explicitopening is required

#### repl.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

# Read the hash from `repl.txt`
my %repl = do {
    open my $fh, '<', 'repl.txt' or die $!;
    map { chomp; split ' ', $_, 2; } <$fh>;
};

# Build and compile regex pattern
my $re = join '|', map { "\\b$_\\b" } keys %repl;
$re = qr/$re/;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    s/($re)/$repl{$1}/g;
    print;
}

__DATA__
ID1 X1 X2 X3
ID2 X3 X4 X5
```

#### output

```
ID1 X2 X3 X7 X8
ID2 X8 X4 X5
```

### Update

If you prefer two separate files for the keys and values of the hash, then change the loading of hash like this

#### col1

```
X1
X2
X3
```

#### col2

```
X2 X3
X7
X8
```

#### Code to load hash `%repl`

```
my %repl;
{
    my $fh;

    open $fh, '<', 'col1' or die $!;
    my @keys = map { chomp; $_; } <$fh>;

    open $fh, '<', 'col2' or die $!;
    my @vals = map { chomp; $_; } <$fh>;

    @repl{@keys} = @vals;
}
```

Comment: I think it'd be safer to sort `keys %repl` on their length, and, assuming the OP wants literal matches, to use `quotemeta`, i.e. `my ($re) = map {qr/$_/} join '|', map {quotemeta} sort {length $b<=>length $a} keys %repl;`. See [Building Regex Alternations Dynamically](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1179840).

Comment: @Borodin Awesome!!! I never was able to do that with Perl by my own. Thank you very much for your help this works really great and it's exactly what I was asking.

Comment: @panconchoclo If your input data is not as simple as you've shown in the question, specifically if your search keys from `repl.txt` have non-word characters and differing lengths, then this code, as currently shown, may randomly not work correctly. See the code and link I provided in the comment above.

Comment: @haukex: You may have a point about `quotemeta`, but there is no need to sort the keys by descending length because of the enclosing `\b` anchors.

Comment: @panconchoclo: I have assumed that your data is all alphanumeric, as you have shown in your question. If it could contain Perl *regex metacharacters* (any of `{ } [ ] ( ) ^ $ . | * + ? \ ` ) then you need to take special measures, so let me know.

Comment: @haukex: Note that sorting by descending length is only useful if *all* of the data tokens can be found in the hash. If some tokens should not be replaced and do not appear in the hash then there may still be keys that are substrings of those tokens and the procedure will break. Boundary anchors are necessary. Yes, I got your meaning. I just overlooked `\W` characters at the *ends* of the string defeating the `\b` anchor. It would have to be `map { "(?<!\S)$_(?!\S)" } keys %repl` which I don't want to post unless I have to!

Comment: Yes, I didn't mean that the `\b` isn't necessary, and I could have written the code snippet in my first comment as `my ($re) = map {qr/\b(?:$_)\b/} join ...` to be more in line with your code. And of course the circumstances under which the code might break are complex, but in general I'd still recommend sorting on length to have it work under *all* circumstances - your lookaround suggestion still [breaks](https://gist.github.com/haukex/c0f06c3d11728a89a6a89f879ea32405) if the keys contain whitespace, sorting on length fixes that 

Answer (score 0):

In the first replacement, add some "guard" characters around the string, or otherwise make it unique.  Then make your second replacement pattern ignore such guarded tokens, and finally remove the guards.

For example if you want to replace "A" with "B" and "B" with "A", you can replace "A" with "_A_", "B" with "A", then "_A_" with "B".

Comment: I thought the same but actually this sed line is doing all at once. So there is not a first and second round of replacements using sed in this way.

Comment: The idiomatic way to do that would be to create a placeholder string that cannot exist in the input (`@Y` in the following), map A to that then map B to A then map that placeholder string to A and then restore the original mapping that made it possible to create the placeholder, e.g. to do that with sed would be the following: `sed 's/@/@X/g; s/A/@Y/g; s/B/A/g; s/@Y/A/g; s/@X/@/g'`. That's very much overkill for this question of course.

Answer (score 0):

sed is only for simple substitutions on individual lines and you shouldn't use a shell loop to manipulate text (see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)). For anything else you should use awk for simplicity, clarity, robustness, efficiency, portability, etc.:

```
$ awk '
    NR==FNR { map[$1]=$2; next }
    { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=($i in map ? map[$i] : $i); print }
' FS='\t' repl.txt FS=' ' file
ID1 X2 X3 X7 X8
ID2 X8 X4 X5
```

The above will work robustly and efficiently using any awk in any shell on any UNIX system. Note that it's using literal strings and so will not fail if/when your old or new strings contain regexp or backreference metacharacters or any other characters, unlike the sed script in your question.

The input files used above are the following, with the old vs new values in repl.txt tab-separated:

```
$ cat repl.txt
X1      X2 X3
X2      X7
X3      X8

$ cat file
ID1 X1 X2 X3
ID2 X3 X4 X5
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '1d;s#(\S+)\s*(.*)#s/\\n\1\\n/\2/#' replacementFile |
sed -re 's/\S+/\n&\n/g' -f - -e 's/\n//g' inputFile
```

Use the `replacementFile` to create a sed script and combine this with some boilerplate sed code.

The first set of sed commands creates sed substitution commands with the LHS being the values to substituted and RHS the replacement. The LHS is surrounded by newlines.

The second set of sed commands, first surrounds all values by newlines, then uses the script from the first set of sed commands and lastly removes the newlines.

Since all values are expected to surrounded by newlines and those that are replaced are not, there can be no confusion about substituting the wrong values.